# How to ignore delayed Android Alarms?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have multiple repeating alarms.

For example, if they repeat every hour:

I don't want to take action for an alarm that should have been triggered at 08:00 AM but couldn't because the phone was off from 06:45 AM to 08:45.
When the phone turns on, i only want to take action for the alarm that takes place on 09:00AM not for 08:00 AM or 07:00 AM.